# Changing nameserver on registar

Tags: domains, nameserver, amazon-aws

Im changing the nameserver some domains that I have registered on register365, they allow a user to enter two nameservers and a tertiary nameserver. The new nameservers I am using are AWS which has four nameservers. I was wondering do I need to use all four of these or does that matter? Also what is the tertiary nameserver?

Comment: No, two is sufficient however the 3rd is used more as an added backup measure, 4 would be unnecessary

Comment: Ok thanks thats what I was thinking just wanted to be 100% on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, two nameservers are required, and three are sufficient.  Four is overkill.